# Extract Desired Columns from the dataset via Perl

Tags: perl, dataset

I have got 2 files where in file1 (sample.txt) it is the list of samples IDs (which is around 1000). These sample IDs are the column name in the file2 (sampleValue.txt). The file2 is a data matrix of 30000*1500. I am interested in values of all the rows in 1000 columns out of 1500 which are like 1,2,5,6,70,71,75,100,112,114 and so on. There is no pattern on the columns. So, here is what I am doing and would like to know how can I improve it. Here is my code:

```
## Opening first file
open my $IN, "sample.txt" or die $!;
my $header = <$IN>;

while(<$IN>){
chomp $_;
my @line = split('\t', $_);
$sampleID{$line[0]} = 1; ## Sample ID
}
close($IN);
print "Total number of sample ID: ", scalar(keys %sampleID),"\n"; ## 1000 columns

## Sample Value Data
open $IN, "sampleValue.txt" or die $!;

## Columns are sample names from file1
$header = <$IN>;
my @samples = split("\t", $header); ## 
print "Total samples: ",scalar(@samples),"\n"; ## 1500

## loop for all the samples ids or the columns I am interested in
for(my $i = 1; $i <= $#samples; $i++){ ## bcos the first instance is called header of the column 1
my $sample = $samples[$i];
$sampleValue{$sample} = $i if (exists $sampleID{$sample});
}

my $col = "";  
foreach my $key (keys %sampleValue){
$col = $sampleValue{$key}.",".$col;
}
chop($col);
print $col,"\n"; ## string of all the columns I am interested in
```

The reason I do the above loop because I don't want to look for the interested columns thru the hash while reading the file line by line.

```
## Reading the sample Value file row by row
while(<$IN>){
chomp $_;
print $_,"\n";
my @line = split("\t", $_);
@line = @line[$col]; ## error since it is string type
print @line,"\n";
}
```

I am getting the error for the line `@line = @line[$col];`since, $line is a string and not numeric. But, it works if you do `@line[1,2,5,6,70,71,75,100,112,114]`. So, my question is whether there is an easy way to convert the string `$col` to numeric cols with commas in it or a better way to get the desired columns ?

Comment: I haven't examined all your code, but I think what you could do to get the sequence of numbers from the `$col` string would be `@line = @line[ split /,/, $col];`

Comment: Hey Chris.. you are AWESOME !! Works like a CHARM !!